# how to return all query when I select a checkbox?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I select checkbox or mulitple checkbox it only return 1 row of my database data, how to show all data from database?

```
<?php foreach($portControllerClass->getAllAgencies() as $port_list){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="port[]" value="<?=$port_list['agencies']?>"> <?=$port_list['agencies'] . '</br>'; 
} ?>

$date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_from']));
$date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_to']));

foreach($_POST['port'] as $port){ 

   $sql = "SELECT @a:=@a+1 no, letter_no, letter_date, conformity_date,
                  agencies, DATEDIFF(`conformity_date`,`letter_date`) AS DiffDate 
           FROM info_lab, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a 
           WHERE agencies LIKE '%". implode(",",$_POST['port']) ."%' 
            and conformity_date BETWEEN '".$date_from."' 
            and '".$date_to."'";

   $query = $con->query($sql);
   $row = $query->fetch_array();
   echo $row['letter_no'];
}
```

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST);` to your script and show us what that returns **(edit your question)** dont post as a comment

Comment: show your html code with checkbox code

Comment: Please post html code as well as print_r($_POST) output

Comment: output of print_r($_POST) = Array ( [port] => Array ( [0] => Jeddah Islamic Port ) [date_from] => 04/01/2016 [date_to] => 05/26/2016 [submit] => Submit ) 542,  but query must return 2 row.

Comment: note this code is terrible for SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $_POST['port'] in your query use $port.

So your query would become:

```
$sql = "SELECT @a:=@a+1 no, letter_no, letter_date, conformity_date,
              agencies, DATEDIFF(`conformity_date`,`letter_date`) AS DiffDate 
       FROM info_lab, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a 
       WHERE agencies LIKE '%".$port."%' 
        and conformity_date BETWEEN '".$date_from."' 
        and '".$date_to."'";
```

And if there is more than one row for each data then add this bit of code after $query = $con->query($sql);

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['letter_no'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: this query returning only 1 row of my data sir

Comment: This query should return one row each time foreach is executed. So if you have two checkboxes selected you should get two bits of string displayed. They might be merged together if code above is correct, because I dont see any styling for that line.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Jeddah Islamic Port [1] => King Abdulaziz Seaport - Dammam ) 1529 Array ( [0] => Jeddah Islamic Port [1] => King Abdulaziz Seaport - Dammam ) 4475, I selected 2checkboxed, it returns 2. but the first array must return 2 query.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve? Can you explain please.

Comment: Jeddah Islamic Port have 2 data on database, but only returning 1 data.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 input checkbox, so you can get only one value. To get multiple values, I think you should use `foreach` loop with checkbox values from database like below:

```
foreach ($port_list['agencies'] as $value){
 <input type="checkbox" name="port[]" value="<?php echo $port_list['agencies']?>"> <php echo $port_list['agencies'] . '</br>'; ?>    
}
```

ALso, please dont use `<?=` tag as it is deprecated, use `<?php ?>` instead

Comment: yes, it's only returning 1 row each query. but i have 2rows on my quer.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Jeddah Islamic Port [1] => King Abdulaziz Seaport - Dammam ) 1529 Array ( [0] => Jeddah Islamic Port [1] => King Abdulaziz Seaport - Dammam ) 4475,    I selected 2checkboxed, it returns 2.  but the first array must return 2 query.